# AngularJS check if one of the gender button is pressed

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

How do I check in AngularJs 1.4.2 how one of my two gender buttons is selected.
Input fields are no problem to check but the buttons - this in not clear for me.

```
<div class="btn-group">
   <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="vm.user.sex" name="sex" btn-radio="'MALE'" uncheckable required="!user.sex">Male</label>
   <label class="btn btn-default" ng-model="vm.user.sex" name="sex" btn-radio="'FEMALE'" uncheckable required="!user.sex">Female</label>
   <span class="errorMessage" ng-show="signupForm.sex.$error">Gender must be selected</span> <!-- This does not work -->
</div>
```

Comment: I would not suggest you to use ng-model on labels.

Comment: @ashfaq.p It doesn't matter as it's both recommended markup for Bootstrap and AngularUI's radio directive also doesn't restrict what tag it is applied on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check `signupForm.sex.$error.required` because `signupForm.sex.$error` alone is always truthy since it's and object:

```
<span class="errorMessage" ng-show="signupForm.sex.$error.required">Gender must be selected</span>
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/r65rVaTJFNmI0d4d716r?p=info